# xcode LLVM 5.1 clang error

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-construction, llvm

I am having no luck the last few days since Xcode 5.1 came out.

I keep getting this error on an old project that supports iOS 6.0:

```
ERROR:

clang: error: unknown argument: '-fno-obj-arc' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

There are not many posts about this on the internet and some suggestions seem to be to change your `CFLAGS` but I have no idea how to do that in Xcode.

Apple suggests this from their documents:

> Compiler
>
> As of Apple LLVM compiler version 5.1 (clang-502) and later, the
>   optimization level -O4 no longer implies link time optimization (LTO).
>   In order to build with LTO explicitly use the -flto option in addition
>   to the optimization level flag. (15633276) The Apple LLVM compiler in
>   Xcode 5.1 treats unrecognized command-line options as errors. This
>   issue has been seen when building both Python native extensions and
>   Ruby Gems, where some invalid compiler options are currently
>   specified. Projects using invalid compiler options will need to be
>   changed to remove those options. To help ease that transition, the
>   compiler will temporarily accept an option to downgrade the error to a
>   warning:
>
> `-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future`
>
> Note: This option will not be supported in the future. To workaround
>   this issue, set the ARCHFLAGS environment variable to downgrade the
>   error to a warning. For example, you can install a Python native
>   extension with:
>
> `$ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future easy_install ExtensionName`
>
> Similarly, you can install a Ruby Gem with:
>
> `$ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future gem install GemName 16214764 updated`

How do I get this workaround?  Obviously Apple has messed up because it should only be presenting me with a warning and not an error according to their documents.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I can not build my app until this issue is rectified.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)

Comment: Suspect the [similar Pillow compile fix might help](http://garmoncheg.blogspot.com/2014/04/pillow-compile-error-clang-wno.html)

Answer (score 12):

There is no such thing as `-fno-obj-arc`. This *never* was working correctly; you just weren't seeing the warnings. The correct form is `-fno-objc-arc`.

EDIT (appended info drawn from my comments below): This is not a clang error. It is an error in the project; clang is merely reporting it. The project itself wrongly contains the `-fno-obj-arc` argument, probably in the Compile Sources build phase of the target (as described here: [How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)). It is easy to type the setting incorrectly; what has changed in Xcode 5.1 is merely that clang is now calling the problem to your attention. Thus, as I said before, this *never* was working correctly; you presumably intended to turn off ARC for certain files, but you were failing to do so, as the build argument was incorrectly entered.

Comment: Where would i possibly put -fno-obj-arc in my code? What i mean is, all my code conforms to Xcode and i see no errors.  The error is in clang, as shown above in the error i am getting.

Comment: No. Clang is reporting your error. You have put this for some of your files, probably in the build phases of your target. - it is your project. It did not fall from heaven. You wrote it. You made an error. Fix it.

Comment: @user1311069 The simplest solution is probably to use the Xcode 5.0.2 clang, as I explain here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22467108/341994

Answer (score 6):

Update to xcode now throws unknown compiler flags as hard errors rather than warnings. Found this to be helpful:

https://langui.sh/2014/03/10/wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future-is-a-harsh-mistress/

Comment: ```export ARCHFLAGS="-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future"```

Comment: And if you're using `sudo`, `sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=nused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future your command here`

Comment: @msc, your answer should be *the* answer. I've returned to this site a dozen or so times to use that command.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out with a small bit of help from matt.
I was trying to figure out where to change the -fno-obj-arc and NO ONE answered that question.
I found this link to be helpful...
http://blog.evanmulawski.com/?p=36

Once you select build phases and compile sources, you can look next to the files in your project and change their build flags.

Thanks for the attempt guys.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Comment: Well, also this answer describes the situation incorrectly. What I provided was not merely "a small bit of help". The OP kept insisting that clang itself was in error and that `-fno-obj-arc` was something that _it_ was saying. My answer, plus repeated comments, were needed to get the OP to understand that clang was merely _reporting_ the error, which was in the project itself. Moreover, my comments did explain where the error was likely to be found.

Answer (score 2):

```
export ARCHFLAGS="-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future"
```

Comment: and remember it won't migrate if you are using `sudo` , so su to root and install that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change -fno-obj-arc to -fno-objc-arc.
Select project -> targets -> build phases ..see picture[image]