# iOS Can't build/deploy my application anymore after Xcode 5.1 update

Tags: ios, xcode

i just encountered a weird issue right after updating my Xcode 5.0 to 5.1.. the error occurs while building my application..

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-fno-obc-arc' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

i Can't build my application anymore…? serious issue please help.. thanks in advance..

If u need further info feel free to ask..

Comment: Your compiler flag needs to be `-fno-objc-arc`. There is a typo in it.

Comment: i did that but still its giving the same error

Comment: Did you correct the typo?

Comment: Yes i corrected it to `-fno-objc-arc` and restarted xcode too but still same issue...

Comment: i also tried a clean build combo but nothing...

Comment: This looks similar to your issue: [xcode LLVM 5.1 clang error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394575/xcode-llvm-5-1-clang-error)

Comment: i saw that but issue is i haven't used it in my code… neither can i find it in find option...

Comment: Check Project -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources. Individual `.m` files are marked with this compiler flag.

Comment: yes there are a few but all are with `-fno-objc-arc`

Comment: Are you using any libraries which may have wrong flag set internally?

Comment: i have used AFNetwork, XMPP Framework, IDZAQ OGG Library, and a few more little libraries…

Comment: Any way you can check if they have this wrong flag set? Or may be try with their ARC enabled versions.

Comment: i can't think of any way… let me try that

Comment: xcode keeps crashing on changing -fno-objc-arc… ahhhh

Comment: @Amar still no luck….

Comment: May be you can try creating a completely new project by piecing in individual library and figure out which one could be causing issue. Also it would be worth trying to compile your project on a different machine with Xcode 5.1

Comment: If nothing works, better to downgrade Xcode back to 5.0 where your project was compiling.

Comment: oh that would be a very long process… downgrading aill be the only solution rytnow