# Apple LLVM 5.1 Error When Building nds4ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

```
ProcessPCH /Users/sachinmansukhani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/nds4ios-chkgruuwffdlbnewmhmwzxcpmeom/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/nds4ios-Prefix-cvqubcffbrdtbidyqsfmamzmeveu/nds4ios-Prefix.pch.pch nds4ios/support/nds4ios-Prefix.pch normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd /Users/sachinmansukhani/Documents/nds4ios
export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c-header -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Ofast -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -DIOS -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -miphoneos-version-min=7.1 -iquote /Users/sachinmansukhani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/nds4ios-chkgruuwffdlbnewmhmwzxcpmeom/Build/Intermediates/nds4ios.build/Debug-iphoneos/nds4ios.build/nds4ios-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/sachinmansukhani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/nds4ios-chkgruuwffdlbnewmhmwzxcpmeom/Build/Intermediates/nds4ios.build/Debug-iphoneos/nds4ios.build/nds4ios-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/sachinmansukhani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/nds4ios-chkgruuwffdlbnewmhmwzxcpmeom/Build/Intermediates/nds4ios.build/Debug-iphoneos/nds4ios.build/nds4ios-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/sachinmansukhani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/nds4ios-chkgruuwffdlbnewmhmwzxcpmeom/Build/Intermediates/nds4ios.build/Debug-iphoneos/nds4ios.build/nds4ios-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/sachinmansukhani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/nds4ios-chkgruuwffdlbnewmhmwzxcpmeom/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include -I/Users/sachinmansukhani/Documents/nds4ios/Classes -I/Users/sachinmansukhani/Documents/nds4ios/nds4droid-code/jni/desmume/src -I/Users/sachinmansukhani/Documents/nds4ios -I/Users/sachinmansukhani/Documents/nds4ios/nds4droid-code/jni/desmume/src/android -I/Users/sachinmansukhani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/nds4ios-chkgruuwffdlbnewmhmwzxcpmeom/Build/Intermediates/nds4ios.build/Debug-iphoneos/nds4ios.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/Users/sachinmansukhani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/nds4ios-chkgruuwffdlbnewmhmwzxcpmeom/Build/Intermediates/nds4ios.build/Debug-iphoneos/nds4ios.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/sachinmansukhani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/nds4ios-chkgruuwffdlbnewmhmwzxcpmeom/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/sachinmansukhani/Documents/nds4ios -F/Users/sachinmansukhani/Documents/nds4ios/nds4ios/frameworks -F/Users/sachinmansukhani/Documents/nds4ios/nds4ios -F/Users/sachinmansukhani/Documents/nds4ios/nds4ios/dropbox -F/Users/sachinmansukhani/Documents/nds4ios/nds4ios/Reveal -DANDROID -fexceptions -ftree-vectorize -fsingle-precision-constant -fprefetch-loop-arrays -fvariable-expansion-in-unroller -DCOMPRESS_MT -DIOS -DHAVE_LIBZ -marm --serialize-diagnostics /Users/sachinmansukhani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/nds4ios-chkgruuwffdlbnewmhmwzxcpmeom/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/nds4ios-Prefix-cvqubcffbrdtbidyqsfmamzmeveu/nds4ios-Prefix.pch.dia -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/sachinmansukhani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/nds4ios-chkgruuwffdlbnewmhmwzxcpmeom/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/nds4ios-Prefix-cvqubcffbrdtbidyqsfmamzmeveu/nds4ios-Prefix.pch.d -c /Users/sachinmansukhani/Documents/nds4ios/nds4ios/support/nds4ios-Prefix.pch -o /Users/sachinmansukhani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/nds4ios-chkgruuwffdlbnewmhmwzxcpmeom/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/nds4ios-Prefix-cvqubcffbrdtbidyqsfmamzmeveu/nds4ios-Prefix.pch.pch

clang: error: unknown argument: '-fsingle-precision-constant' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
clang: error: unknown argument: '-fvariable-expansion-in-unroller' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Help?

Comment: Please give us more information as to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

A major change in Xcode 5.1 is that the version of clang that it contains no longer accepts unknown/invalid arguments. You are trying to build something that uses arguments `-fsingle-precision-constant` and `-fvariable-expansion-in-unroller` and these are no longer legal.

You must take this up with whoever is responsible for whatever it is you are trying to build (in this case, something called "nds4ios", apparently). They need to create new source code whose build commands do not include bad arguments.

Alternatively, revert temporarily to the clang inside Xcode 5.0.2. To do so, install Xcode 5.0.2, and then, in Xcode 5.1, open Preferences, switch to the Locations pref pane, and switch the Command Line Tools pop-up menu to Xcode 5.0.2.